# How do I configure OTRS to use the ITSM add-on packages I've installed?

Tags: otrs

I've got my OTRS system up and running and I now need to configure it to use the ITSM addons for Asset Management.
I've downloaded and installed these packages using the OTRS Package Manager:
[image: OTRS Package Manager]

As far as I understand, I now need to configure the /opt/otrs/Kernel/config.pm file, but I'm not sure how. I've tried to edit the file using my otrsuser but am having some difficulty even accessing the file:

[image: otrsuser]

Is there a step-by-step guide available on how to do this please?

Sorry, I forgot to list the packages I installed using the OTRS Package Manager. I installed these:

```
ImportExport.opm 
ITSMServiceLevelManagement.opm 
ITSMIncidentProblemManagement.opm 
ITSMCore.opm 
ITSMConfigurationManagement.opm 
ITSMChangeManagement.opm 
GeneralCatalog.opm
```

Comment: Not as a comment add the info to the question via edit.

Answer (score 0):

After the packages are installed, you need to add the permission groups to your user.

You may need to log out and log in again and then you should be able to see the ITSM related menu modules.

Comment: Thank you Hannes.

Comment: Thank you Hannes.

It appears that my packages are actually not installing. I downloaded v6.0.30 files from Github, then followed the process of installing GeneralCatalog.opm first, followed by ITSMCore.opm.

When I then try to install the OTRS-CE-ITSMConfigurationManagement-6.0.31.opm package, I get the following message:
REQUIRED OTRS PACKAGES
 * ITSMCore 6.0.30

When I install ITSMCore.opm my OTRS system just displays a blank page, no confirmation and no files added to my local repository.

Yesterday afternoon I managed to enable AllowNotVerifiedPackages.